# Weekend maintenance window GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to set the maintenance window for the Google Kubernetes Engine for weekends via terraform. In the console it is an easy thing:

[image]

Now, to persist through terraform, I did sth like:

```hcl
  maintenance_policy {
    recurring_window {
      start_time = "2019-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      end_time = "2019-01-01T23:59:00Z"
      recurrence = "FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=SA,SU"
    }
  }
```

What results in:

[image]

Is it correct way? Can I write a terraform code in a way that I get the result presented in the first image?

Comment: Why have you set your start and end time to the start of 2019?

Comment: Because this time is used only to calculate the duration of the maintenance window. In the https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#nested_maintenance_policy:

The start time's date is the initial date that the window starts, and the end time is used for calculating duration.

Comment: Or I misunderstand it.